# PHP readfile from external server, which IP?

Tags: php, curl

I plan to use a server A to "proxy" the download of files located in another server B. So a user will click on a link on server A, to download the file located in server B.

I know about the php readfile() function, and it is working when I pass a URL to it (for example http://serveurB/file.pdf).

However, do you know what sees the server B? Does he know the user is downloading the file, or does he think the server A is downloading the file (what I want)?

here is my code:

```
$filename = $download_url[1];

$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
header('Content-Type: ' . finfo_file($finfo, $filename));
finfo_close($finfo);

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filename));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($filename);
exit;
```

Comment: If the link is to server B then B should know.

Comment: Why don't you simply try what you have in mind and check yourself what "the server B sees"?

Comment: Apart from that: take a look at using your http servers rewriting module to proxy such requests.

Comment: I tried to pass a link of a file hosted on my server (server A, because I don't have any other), and by inspecting the logs of my webserver, the IP address is server A's IP address, and not the user's.
I will mark the post as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, using your description and sample code, the target server ('server B') will not be aware of the original user request to 'server A'.

The server running your php script (A) will be doing a HTTP 1.0 GET request to server B to get the file.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php